# Can i copy data from a win X to a normal usb just by plugginf it in?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I would like to know if with the windows 10 update there is a way to just stick in a normal usb into a pc and copy some specific data like instantly (i am new with this type of things so i don't know much about it please explain easy) i tried with the usual ways i found on the internet like do a autorun.inf to auto execute it but doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Windows so that it will do this

1. On Windows start menu, click on the *Settings* menu item.
2. Click on the *Devices* icon.
3. Click on the *AutoPlay* option in the list to the left.
4. Click on the *Use AutoPlay for all media and devices* option to turn it on.

I believe it is turned off by default because of the danger of a virus or other malware infecting your computer immediately you plug in a USB mass storage device.

Comment: thx i will  try  it